# Launcher icon differences in pixels between monitors usign same resolution

Tags: launcher, icons

Today I got to test a Samsung SyncMaster 2043nwx. My normal monitor was a 1080p Soniview TV that supports 1920x1080. I use 1680x1050 (16:10) as my common resolution. My amazed is when I see that the launcher icons looks more to a "correct size" of 32px to what they show in my Soniview where they actually take about 50% more using the same resolution. They are both the same resolution but in the Soniview the launcher icons look 50% bigger than the ones in the Samsung.

My question is then, why the difference between both monitors since they are using the same resolution but are showing different launcher icon sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a difference in PPI (pixels per inch) between the monitors.  There's something going on between the EDID PPI, the actual PPI, and possibly a resolution translation with your other monitor.  For example if you have to change screen dynamics to make the display fit the whole screen, it might get shrunk or stretched to do so.

You would have to compare both screens running in their native resolutions, and take into account the real PPI: Doing so would probably more closely give the results that you expect to see.

Comment: Thanks fabricator4, what apps do you recommend to read/modify the current PPI to test it.

Comment: You can't change the ppi, it's a function of the physical characteristics of the screen.  Most programs will assume a ppi of 72 for reporting purposes, but actual ppi may be different.  More important is the native resolution of the screen: the resolution that it is designed to run at so that the pixels displayed match the physical pixels of the screen.  It is generally the resolution that the monitor will look best in, regardless of the preferences of the user.